# how to restrict C function on server to run at most ONE instance of this function at any moment in time?

Tags: c

My (Linux) application server has an (ANSI) C function on it that clients may access to perform number crunching. I understand the way servers generally work is they take requests from multiple clients and process these requests in parallel. That is, the same C function on the server may be called (and more importantly, may be run) as many times as there are clients wishing to use it (assuming sufficient system resources, e.g. CPU, memory, etc.).

The problem is one call to the C function uses practically the entire server resources. For the sake of discussion, assume the system crashes if two instances of the C function are run simultaneously.

QUESTION: Is there a way I can make sure that at most only one instance of this function is ever allowed to run (simultaneously)?

Comment: is this a threaded or forked application? the solution will depend heavily on that question.

Comment: My guess is forked. There's nothing in the C code specifically creating a multi-threaded application.

Comment: either you're calling fork() or you're calling pthread_create (or it's a single-threaded application, period, in which case your question is moot); which does grep tell you is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what a mutex is for - to permit mutual exclusion.  Only one instance/thread/process can lock a mutex.  Other entities will fail when they try, and will continue to fail until the owner unlocks the mutex.

Comment: pthread mutex isn't the only mutex one could use,
and even if it was, there is still shared memory.
If one file needs to be locked, pid file is sufficient, otherwise I'd go for ipc (posix).

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of ways of doing it.  For your purposes, I think the simple, old-fashioned technique of a lock file is probably as good as any and better than some.  The function (or a wrapper for the function) will look to see if it can create a lock file.  If it can, it goes ahead and runs, and then removes the lock file when it is done.  If it can't create the file, it looks to see what the file contains - it should be a PID of the last process to run the function.  If the PID still exists (check with `kill(0, pid)`), then you're not allowed to run.  If the PID does not exist, then it died without cleaning up its lock file, and you should ... worry about whether there's another process also detecting that the PID is not there.